# Wake monitor from sleep remotely

Tags: openbox, sleep

I have an Ubuntu server running `xdm` with `openbox` on which is plugged a monitor that displays a video which is launched via a cron daemon.

When the monitor is not used for a certain amount of time, it goes into sleep mode and I cannot wake it up with the video process : The monitor stays black.

How can I wake the monitor? Without installing packages if possible, and without a physical access to the machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
xset --help

usage:  xset [-display host:dpy] option ...

    To control Energy Star (DPMS) features:
    -dpms      Energy Star features off
    +dpms      Energy Star features on
     dpms [standby [suspend [off]]]
          force standby
          force suspend
          force off
          force on
          (also implicitly enables DPMS features)
          a timeout value of zero disables the mode
```

So if you get the `${DISPLAY}` of the monitor you can:

```
xset -display ${DISPLAY} dpms force on
```

Comment: What if I do it via `ssh`?

Comment: @DeerHunter Then you use the display number.

Comment: it works (without the need to specify the display (I have only one)). Thanks !

Comment: @Jav - I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: and I meant : it works via ssh

Comment: Will this disable automatic sleep timer?

Comment: I'll let you know in 30 minutes

Comment: @Michael No it won't.

Comment: `xset -display :0 dpms force on` works for me when I log in via ssh